# How insert field name when using internationalization with javax validations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, internationalization, bean-validation

I'm using javax validation annotations with Spring Boot and internationalization. So I have the following field:

```
@Size(min = 3, max = 3, message = "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}")
private String currencyCode;
```

The US resource bundle has:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message = size must be between {min} and {max}
```

So when this field fails on validation, I see the message `"size must be between 3 and 3"`.

But what I want is to have a message like:

```
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message = {fieldName}'s size must be between {min} and {max}
```

Which would result in the message `"currencyCode's size must be between 3 and 3"`.

Is this possible? Do I need to override a bean to make it work? Is there a pre-defined property for the field name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create handler for MethodArgumentNotValidException

```
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public Object handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(final MethodArgumentNotValidException e) { ...
```

inside them you can invoke

```
 e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
```

This is collection with all informations about invalid field error eg. field name, rejected value.

At next, use message like in your's example and use **StrSubstitutor** from **org.apache.commons.lang3**. Just create map of parameters

key -->  fieldName , value --> currencyCode

Of course you have to write some code, but here is the solution :)

Comment: What do you mean use StrSubstitutor?

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially the answer. I'll just use `fieldError.getDefaultMessage().replace( "{fieldName}", fieldError.getField() );`

Comment: I mean this
`Map valuesMap = HashMap(); 
 valuesMap.put("animal", "quick brown fox");
 valuesMap.put("target", "lazy dog");
 String templateString = "The ${animal} jumps over the ${target}.";
 StrSubstitutor sub = new StrSubstitutor(valuesMap);
 String resolvedString = sub.replace(templateString);`

and result 
`The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.`
But yours solution is also good

Answer (score 0):

By default @Size annotation does not provide option to put label in the message, instead you can create your own implementation like below so that it can be used across your application:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = MySizeValidator.class)
public @interface MySize {

    String message() default "{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int min() default 0;

    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {

        Size[] value();
    }

    public abstract String label();
}
```

then create your own validator like MySizeValidator to validate MySize annotation like below

```
public class MySizeValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MySize, String> {

    private static final Log log = LoggerFactory.make();

    private int min;
    private int max;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MySize parameters) {
        min = parameters.min();
        max = parameters.max();
        validateParameters();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String field, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (field == null) {
            return true;
        }
        int length = field.length();
        return length >= min && length <= max;
    }

    private void validateParameters() {
        if (min < 0) {
            throw log.getMinCannotBeNegativeException();
        }
        if (max < 0) {
            throw log.getMaxCannotBeNegativeException();
        }
        if (max < min) {
            throw log.getLengthCannotBeNegativeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Create `ValidationMessages.properties` with below key value

javax.validation.constraints.mySize.message={label}'s size must be between {min} and {max}

then in your POJO, you can put this new annotation,

```
@MySize(min = 3, max = 3, message = "{javax.validation.constraints.mySize.message}", label = "Currency Code")
    private String currencyCode;
```

Comment: In that solution, you need to format label also correctly for eg; fieldName is currencyCode in POJO but then you have to show "Currency Code" on the screen, then you need to put a map somewhere if field currencyCode is coming then replace it with Currency Code. One more issue is if you have two POJOs with same field Name with with different description, like at one time you want to return label as "Current Code" and at other time you want to return label as "Currency" then the hack solution will be messy, whereas creating own validator/annotation is a clean solution which is used by spring too

Comment: But its your call, I thought to provide a clean solution

Comment: Labels should be a client-side thing anyways, not driven by the server. But your point is a valid one.

Comment: @AmitKBist Your's solution is quite better, but common `@Size` annotation was tested and etc. Generally i think that creating own validators for models is much better than annotations/attribs for fields in this model. Annotations breaks OOP but it takes less time. Sad but true.